# Appending to an existing workflow in WF 4.5

Tags: workflow-foundation-4

I am using WF Services 4.5 and have a need to correlate a user-supplied order id with a workflow id, so that the user can later append items to the same order (and workflow) if the order is still in process (the workflow has not completed).  It's expected that the user will continue to build up the order while the workflow is still in process.

In my initial implementation, I have used the InitializeCorrelationActivity to correlate the external order id with a correlation handle for the workflow instance (content correlation).

I have put the Receive/SendReplyToReceive messaging activities in a While loop to allow for multiple calls to the same workflow, but the second call to the service throws an exception, due to the fact that the correlation handle is already initialized.

How should I be appending to a workflow that's already in progress using WF Services?  Is there a way to look up an existing correlation before manually initializing one?  Is there a better approach to this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand why are you using while loop?
Every single order should be represented as another instance of the same workflow, so if you have 10 orders, you have 10 different processes. It's up to you if you correlate workflow process id or order id to identify specific order.
To get a collection of working processes use Tracking Participant. Look here for more info: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj205426(v=vs.110).aspx